# MenuFlyout fails

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm having some issues with the MenuFlyouts when showing triggered by a RightTapped event on some MapItems and ListViewItems also, so I supposed that it happens with other controls also.

So, when I open the first MenuFlyout, it works ok. The I choose another MapItem and open its MenuFlyout then again it works ok. BUT, if I open a MenuFlyout while I haven't closed the previous, it opens, but the new MenuFlyout background changes to black and the MenuFlyoutItems that contains (Edit, View, ...) they don't respond to the mouse click, nor taps, ... If I try to open another MenuFlyout, both after closed the previous or without closing, it works ok again.

Then, I have debugged to follow whats happening behind the curtains and I've found that when everything is going ok, the event triggered are in order the next(open process):

- Opening
- Closing
- Closed
- Opening
- Opened

Closing process (ok):

- Closing
- Closed

Opening failed process:

- Closing
- Closing
- Closed
- Opening
- Opened

Look that some events are triggered twice and when opening ok, the first three events are a little bit strange (starts opening, the closes to open it again).

There's no error nor exception message on output window.

Why it is happening? How can I fix it?

Maybe, there's some problem when tries to show a second MenyFlyout and it is not possible? In that case, how can I close the previous one before showing the next one?

Below goes all the code that I think it'll be useful.

Thanks

My MenuFlyout is an ContextFlyout. Here's the XAML code:

```
 <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="mapSpotsItems">
<Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel x:Name="spotPin" Visibility="{Binding isVisible}" Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding NormalizedAnchorPoint}"
                    Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding geopoint}" Tag="{Binding ID}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding AdvancedDescription}" 
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1" 

                    Tapped="spotPin_Tapped" DoubleTapped="spotPin_DoubleTapped" RightTapped="spotPin_RightTapped"
                    PointerEntered="spotPin_PointerEntered" PointerExited="spotPin_PointerExited"
                    >

            <StackPanel.ContextFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout Closing="MenuFlyout_Closing" Closed="MenuFlyout_Closed" Opened="MenuFlyout_Opened" Opening="MenuFlyout_Opening">

                    <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">                
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource AcrylicDarkGrey50Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource DarkGrey10ThemeColor}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>

                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open in Planner" Tag="{Binding ID}" Tapped="spotOpenInPlannerFlyoutItem_Tapped">

                    </MenuFlyoutItem>

                    <MenuFlyoutSeparator  />

                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="View" Tag="{Binding ID}" Tapped="spotViewFlyoutItem_Tapped">            
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit" Tag="{Binding ID}" Tapped="spotEditFlyoutItem_Tapped">
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>

                    <MenuFlyoutSeparator Visibility="{Binding Exportable}"/>

                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Move" Tag="{Binding ID}" Tapped="spotMoveFlyoutItem_Tapped">
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>

                    <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>

                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Export" Tag="{Binding ID}" Visibility="{Binding Exportable}" Tapped="spotExportFlyoutItem_Tapped">
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>

                    <MenuFlyoutSeparator  Visibility="{Binding Exportable}" />

                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Tag="{Binding ID}" Tapped="spotDeleteFlyoutItem_Tapped">
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>

                </MenuFlyout>
            </StackPanel.ContextFlyout>


            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{StaticResource SpotBackgroundColor}" Tag="{Binding ID}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Width="22" Height="22"  Opacity="0.5"/>
                    <Image Source="{Binding MainTag}" Height="20" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>

                <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               Width="50" 
                               MaxLines="2" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" LineHeight="11"
                               Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" 
                               FontSize="11" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="{ThemeResource SpotForegroundColor}" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>

            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Polygon Fill="{StaticResource SpotBackgroundColor}" Points="-5,0, 0,10, 5,0, -5,0" />
            </Canvas>


        </StackPanel>

    </DataTemplate>
</Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</Maps:MapItemsControl>
```

And the C# that opens the MenuFlyout:

```
private async void spotPin_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    onSpotPin = true;

    StackPanel sp = sender as StackPanel;
    sp.ContextFlyout.ShowAt((FrameworkElement)sender);

    await Task.Delay(globalVars.SINGLE_TAP_MIN_TIME * 2);
    onSpotPin = false;

}
```

Here the events of the MenuFlyouts (why Opening, Opened and Closed parameter types are object and Closing on the other hand, has it's own's?):

```
private void MenuFlyout_Opening(object sender, object e)
{

}

private void MenuFlyout_Opened(object sender, object e)
{

}

private void MenuFlyout_Closed(object sender, object e)
{

}

private void MenuFlyout_Closing(FlyoutBase sender, FlyoutBaseClosingEventArgs args)
{

}
```

**UPDATED:**

After trying different ways, finally I have achieved what was my goal: I've created the MenuFlyout and all the items containing by code.

Despite the result, on the way of trying, I've realized that adding or showing the MenuFlyout by code has it's own problems also.

It's curious that when showing the MenuFlyout created by code and attaching to a control, when using this line of code:

```
f.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
```

It works ok and fulfills my needs, but if use the same command but with the second parameter, it fails as explained before:

```
f.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement, e.GetPosition(sender as FrameworkElement));
```

Any idea, why?

**2nd UPDATE AND SOLUTION**

When working with XAML (MenuFlyout defined in XAML), Click event should be chosen instead of Tap event.

When MenuFlyout created in code, Tap event works fine.

Comment: Hello, after setting `ContextFlyout` for the control, the default behavior is to right-click to open the menu without setting the `RightTapped` event again, which may be the reason for repeated triggering.

Comment: Yes. After disabling the event handler of RighTapped , the order of triggers that are happening is:
- Opening
- Opened


And, when closing:
- Closing
- Closed

It seems the logical and the correct, but now, the MenuFlyout doesn't react at all.

Comment: I'm going to try doing it by code.

Comment: Hello, the second method of displaying `MenuFlyout` you said failed, is it an error or does not display `MenuFlyout`? I did not reproduce your problem, `MenuFlyout` pops up normally

Comment: It displays the MenuFlyout. The origin of my problem it is not that the MenuFlyout is not displayed, but despite of having on the screen, it doesn't react to Tap events. This is the case with the second method (with Point parameter on it).

I'm using 1803 as target version.

Comment: For `MenuFlyoutItem`, you should listen to the `Click` event. `Tapped` event is a lower level event, it will be replaced by `Click` event.

Comment: I don't see an ClickEvent in the RoutedEvent posiibilities. Anyway, I think that there's something happening with the MenuFlyout when attached to an MapItemsControl...

Comment: Hi, `MenuFlyoutItem.Click` is an exclusive event of `MenuFlyoutItem`, you can see it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyoutitem.click?view=winrt-18362). So please try to attach the event to the corresponding `MenuFlyoutItem` in Xaml, when you click on the item, the event will be triggered.

Comment: OK. Now I understand. I was talking about the code part and you about the XAML part. I tested and it works ok; reacts to Click events, but not to Tap events. Thank you!